# How to Solve absolute value in Mathematica without Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, absolute, equation, mathematica-8

I have this equation that I can't insert in Mathematica `Abs[x-1]+Abs[x+2]=3`. I tried solve `[Abs[x-1]+Abs[x+2]==3]` but it gives no answer.

I tried NSolve and DSolve and Evaluate but nothing worked. I can get the answer by hand `-2 <= x <= 1` but I need to solve in Mathematica without Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Reduce[Abs[x - 1] + Abs[x + 2] == 3, x, Reals]
```

> -2 <= x <= 1